# Back-end & database technologies suited with react-native

Tags: react-native

Please guide me, which back-end tool (technology/language) and database technology would be best suited for us in a situation when we are working with react native (using expo tool) and major functionality of our project is mainly searching from huge data-set?

Comment: MERN stack seems feasible here. as for the huge data-set, is this a ML app you are trying to build?

Comment: Thanks. The app has just "searching and matching" functionality, not an ML app.